# Trying to call is_active method from outside user model in Django ADMIN

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Here I have a function that bans and unbans users.Currently I can use this in DjangoAdmin in my custom User Model.
But what I am trying to do is ban users from the **Profile** model in my DjangoAdmin as well.

Yet I keep receiving ***ERROR FieldDoesNotExist at /admin/api/profile/

Profile has no field named 'is_active'***   as `is_active` is a function of the User Model.I'm not sure how to go about banning users from the Profile Model view in Admin or how to connect is_active to `Profile` Model.

```
#Banning Function
 def ban_users(self, request, queryset):
     queryset.update(is_active = False)
     self.message_user(request, "User is banned and Email has been sent")

 def remove_ban(self, request, queryset):
     queryset.update(is_active = True)
     self.message_user(request, "Users ban has been lifted")

 #Admin functions will be created here,as well as registration  of their specific models

 class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('user_reported', 'report_reason', 'sent_by', 'session')
 admin.site.register(Report, ReportAdmin)

 class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('user', 'birth_date', 'sessions_played', 'total_reports')
     readonly_fields = (('sessions_played'),('birth_date'),('user'),('pref_server'),('teamwork_commends'),('skill_commends'),('sportsmanship_commends'),('communication_commends'),('discord_name'))#,'total_reports')
     actions = ['ban', 'unban']
     ban = ban_users
     unban = remove_ban

 def total_reports(self, obj):
     return Report.objects.filter(user_reported=obj).count()

 admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)

 class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
     list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name' , 'email')
     readonly_fields = ('first_name' , ('last_name') , ('email') , ('username'))
     actions = ['ban', 'unban']
     ban = ban_users
     unban = remove_ban
 admin.site.unregister(User)
 admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: can you add `Profile` model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action functions assume that the queryset will always contain `User` objects, but because you're using the same action functions for the `ProfileAdmin`, they also need to handle `Profile` objects.

```py
def ban_users(self, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        if hasattr(obj, 'user'):
            # This object is a Profile, so lookup the user
            obj = obj.user
        obj.is_active = False
        obj.save()
    self.message_user(request, "User is banned and Email has been sent")
```

Note that the `queryset.update()` function [cannot be used to update columns on related models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update), hence you cannot do `queryset.update(user__is_active = False)`.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your codes, take a look at what came in my mind.
**untested theory**

since `is_active` is a field of `User`, by having `queryset` we can check whether it's a `Queryset` of `User` or `Profile`.

*knowing that Profile has a conventional `OneToOneField` to User, as I see in many projects*

```
def ban_users(self, request, queryset):
    # select an instance from queryset
    instance = queryset.first()
    if instance.__class__.__name__ == 'Profile'
        queryset.update(user__is_active = False)
    else:
        queryset.update(is_active = False)
    self.message_user(request, "User is banned and Email has been sent")
```

Comment: Hm,Im running into a Syntax Error: Invalid syntax on the line                            

    
`if instance.__class__.__name__ == 'Profile'`

And yes,Profile does have a OneToOneField to User in models :)

Comment: add `print(queryset)` inside the function as first line,and show me the output

Comment: `def ban_users(self, request, queryset):
 print(queryset)
 #select an instance from queryset`

Output is still :

if instance.__class__.__name__ == 'Profile'
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax    Unfortunately

Comment: I meant , i just want to know what is the value of queryset, the type... before the traceback of the issue in your console, you can see the output of `print(queryset)` **scroll up**. if `queryset` is a normal one as we used to do, my answer should work.

Comment: Only line before Traceback is `Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f4f1f6b8bf8>`
It then goes to print the traceback